# How do you install TensorflowLite C++ on a Linux without an ARM processor?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to run and test Tensorflow Lite inference with C++ on a Linux machine. It is not an embedded system and it does not have an ARM processor, which makes it difficult. I have followed the install guide located on the main website (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64), but the install does not work when it gets to the ARM specific part. Can anybody tell me how to install it on a Linux distro that isn't on an ARM processor? How would I then run it? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Seems like you have to build tensorflow lite yourself for your board with the correct config. What kind of processor architecture do you use? x86?

Comment: "tell me how to install it on a Linux distro that isn't on an ARM processor?" Which processor do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using an x86 processor architecture, you can follow the ARM instructions on tensorflow lite and run `build_lib.sh` instead of the build script of the ARM processor.